# Atmega32A fuses

Tags: fuses, atmega

I have Atmega32A and 16 MHz quartz, with 22pF capacitors. Tell me, please, how to set the fuses correctly so that the MK works from external quartz.

Will MK work when setting 0xFF LOW and 0xD8 HIGH? These are the fuses of the Arduino Leonardo

As a result, I want to get a working microcontroller with work from external quartz and that I could rewrite the program.

I use eXtreme Burner - AVR and usbasp

Comment: have you searched for a fuse calculator on the internet?

Comment: Yes. I already set 0xFB LOW and 0x99 HIGH. After that, my microcontroller does not respond. As with the JP3 jumper on usbasp and without it.

Comment: @ОлегС So you've used "Low Freq" Crystal/Resonator... No wonder it's not working with High Freq Crystal

Comment: @ОлегС what exactly is your question? ... your post asks how to set fuses, but then your comment says that you already set the fuses

Comment: @KIIV And what is the difference between `Low Freq 16K CK` and `High Freq 16K CK`?

Comment: @jsotola Probably my question is incorrect. Sorry. I just wanted to know how to properly set the fuses, so as not to spoil the next microcontroller.

Comment: @ОлегС it's usually weaker driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Atmel fuse confuses me a lot so I have figure out an easy way of finding fuses for such controllers basically two methods that I have used once are:

**Method 1:(explaining specific for this controller (
    ATmega1284,
    ATmega644,
    ATmega324,
    ATmega164,
    ATmega32,
    ATmega16,
    ATmega8535
))**

Add [this](https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore) to your Arduino board manager it is from MCU dude they have different varients also for other controllers check [here](https://github.com/MCUdude).

Now select your controller and your clock frequency and all parameters as you like after that use USBASP or Arduino as isp for burning bootloader inside your controller, in this case, we will burn the bootloader into Atmega32A.

After the successful burning bootloader, you will need an [AVRdudess](https://github.com/zkemble/AVRDUDESS) software by using this software you have to just read the fuse of our MCU so we will get the fuse setting done by MCUdude from Arduino and after that, you can directly set those fuse setting and it will work fine.

**Method2:**

just use online calculators such as [here](https://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/) for finding fuse settings.